# Detox animation settings

Tags: detox

Quick question about 16.6.0

In the [release note of 16.6.0](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/16.6.0) is says **"Disabling all native-Android animations on Android emulator"**

Does that mean I don't have to set these globals anymore?

```
adb shell "settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0"
adb shell "settings put global transition_animation_scale 0.0"
adb shell "settings put global animator_duration_scale 0.0"
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Detox now stops animations on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is exactly what it means. More so, Detox will ensure this will be applied even in an environment running tests on multiple emulators, concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

This feature had a bug before and they just fixed it in this release: [18.18.0](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/18.18.0)